# How to enter data to two tables using one form-Special Case

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing this using php,mysql

I have travel group, city, hotel, activity, start date, end date as fields to get information from the user. travel group data goes to one table in mysql database and the rest of the information go to another table..

I want all the data to be filled before clicking on the save button. But while filling only the travel group field and hitting save, the form get submitted, no time to enter other fields as travel group data goes to one separate table. As it is filled it goes to that table. Therefore I want to check whether other details are also filled when hitting on the save button, though the travel group field is filled

Hope My question is clear..Please help me out..I am struggling to do this from yesterday..I am ok with sending data to two tables using one form..But the above mentioned problem still exists..Please help me

Comment: I have used to if statements. one for travel group field and the other for the rest of the fields..I tried using a function to check whether both if statements to ckeck the POST messages are set using isset(). I didnt get any idea beyond that

Comment: update question with code please...

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand you are trying to validate the form. 
you can try `isset()` function in order to check that all the required data is filled in, or you can also try and see that it is of reasonable length using `strlen()`

is this what you were asking for?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using php active records for database handling..ajax is used to send data to the database using post method

Comment: I handled travel group field separately and other fields separately, coz travel group field is in one table and all other fields are in another table..Now the problem is when only the travel group field is filled the form get submitted, no matter the other fields are not filled. When all the fields are emptied and hit on the save button, validations are handled..But when only travel group field is filled the form get submitted..The problem arises when the I fill only the travel group field and hit on save button..

Answer (score 0):

POST the form information (parameters) to another php file which will validate each group separately and will preform two inserts respectively. Then you can redirect the user to any page you want (including the possibility to go back to the form page).